# How to prove and derive coefficients that an exponential whose base decreases exponentially is a parabola

Tags: recurrence-relations, conic-sections, exponential-function

Suppose I have a function defined by this recurrence-relation:

$$R(0) = r$$
$$R(n) = R(n-1) * (1+G)d^{n-1}$$

Here r is a base value, G is a base growth rate (G>0) and d is a decay in the growth rate (d<1).  A real-world example is r=1000000, G=1, d=0.85.

*(For context, this is an equation that appears to govern revenue in year n of a company with revenue r in year 0, which is nominally growing at G per year, because statistically the growth rate of recurring-revenue companies tends to decrease by 85% per year.)*

It seems to me that the function can be simplified (or am I wrong?) to:

$$R(n) = r(1+G)^n d^{n(n-1)/2}$$

I can see by graphing this in Excel and using a parabolic-best-fit that in fact this is exactly a parabola.

I can't understand how to compute that transformation with the general equation, and furthermore since that means there exists A, B, and C such that:

$$R(n) = An^2 + Bn + C$$

How can I produce the values of A, B, and C from the parameters r, G, and d?

Please enlighten me!

Comment: There are no such $A$, $B$, $C$. If you examine the logarithm of your function, yes, it is quadratic in $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function can indeed be simplified like you indicated. In case your simplification is speculative, a brief justification is given in a remark at the end.

The function $R(n)$ is an exponential function, it certainly cannot be expressed as $An^2+Bn+C$ for constants $A$, $B$, and $C$. However, if you define $L(n)$ by $L(n)=\log(R(n))$, then indeed there are $A$, $B$, and $C$ such that $L(n)=An^2+Bn+C$. Te numbers $A$, $B$, and $C$ can be computed readily from your expression for $R(n)$. We get
$$L(n)=\log r+\left(\log(1+G)-\frac{1}{2}\log d\right)n +\frac{1}{2}\log d n^2.$$
Since $\log d$ is negative, one might want to let $c=\frac{1}{d}$ and replace $\log d$ by $-\log c$.

**Remark:** Calculate. We get $R(1)=r(1+G)d^0$, $R(2)=r(1+G)^2d^1$, $R(3)=r(1+G)^3d^{1+2}$, $R(4)=r(1+G)^4d^{1+2+3}$, $R(4)=r(1+G)^5d^{1+2+3+4}$, and so on (the pattern is clear).

So the exponent of $d$ in $R(n)$ is $1+2+3+\cdots +(n-1)$. By the standard formula for the sum of the first $k$ positive integers, the exponent is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. This happens to work also for $n=0$.

Comment: Thanks, so yeah as n increases you can see it's this sigmoidal-looking thing as the decay rate (d) overtakes the growth rate (G).  It's only in the first part of that -- while the function value increases, that it's very nearly a parabola.

Comment: But "very nearly" is an understatement -- it's within less than 1% error.  So would it be accurate to say that at small n (where "small" would have to be defined in terms of the parameters, but with e.g. G=1, d=0.85, then it's when n < 10) it approaches a parabola?

Comment: For small $n$ it would be close. I hadn't realized that $n$ would be so limited.

Comment: *Why* would it be close?  Is there an easy way to see why it collapses with small n like that?  Something akin to sin x = x when x is close to 0?